# Header and footer appear in my table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I don't want the header and the footer to appear in my table of contents. I used `\thispagestyle{empty}` just before `\tableofcontents` and it works... but just for the first page of my table of contents. But my table of contents is composed of 3 pages and the header and footer appear on the second and third pages. How can I manage to make them disappear ?

Thank you for helping me !

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Analysis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could set before the table of contents `\pagestyle{empty}` and after it reset ist to `\pagestyle{plain}` or what you have defined before. It would be easier to help you, if you would include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/33413).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン, that actually won't work because the `\chapter` command within the `\tableofcontents` command resets the page style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```latex
\let\originaltableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \originaltableofcontents
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{fancy}% <- use the page style of the document
}
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}

\let\originaltableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \originaltableofcontents
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{fancy}% <- use the page style of the document
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Or maybe you can use package `tocbasic`:

```latex
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[book.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}% ToC under control of tocbasic
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\cleardoublepage}
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[book.cls]{toc}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}% ToC under control of tocbasic
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:  first, that `\tableofcontents` issues a `\chapter` command, which resets the pagestyle.  It does so in two ways, in fact:  one, it sets the pagestyle of the first page to `plain`, then the normal page style to `headings`.  To cancel this out, you'll have to redefine `\tableofcontents`.  If you find `book.cls`, you can search for it, and then see the changes you'll need to make.  Try the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
     \pagestyle{empty}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother
```

A MWE using this code produced the desired result:  a TOC which consists of pages with the `empty` pagestyle.  Note that you need to do `\thispagestyle{empty}` *before* `\@starttoc`, for the first page; then `\pagestyle{empty}` after it, for the subsequent pages.